# Swap wireless keyboard/mouse receiver(dongle) back and forth between two laptops

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, kvm-switch, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

If I have two laptops connected to two same-brand-and-model wireless keyboard/mouse like so:

Laptop A -> Keyboard/Mouse Pair 1

Laptop B -> Keyboard/Mouse Pair 2

And I swap the USB receiver(dongle), the one in laptop A goes in laptop B and vice-versa, am I right in saying that the end result would be Laptop A now controlled with Keyboard/Mouse Pair 2 and Laptop B controlled with Keyboard/Mouse Pair 1?

Or I would have issues because of pairing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct - the keyboard/mice pairing setup is stored in the ISB receiver (this c an often be reprogrammed with appropriate aoftware though)